# Cannot check if a local variable is null in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to retrieve a value from Chrome local storage using this code:

```
var populateNum = localStorage.getItem('mynum');
if (populateNum) 
  {
    document.getElementById("txtInput").value = populateNum;
  }
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'value' of null

The error is showing in Chrome as being on this line:

```
if (populateNum)
```

Here is the error showing in Chrome://extensions:

[image: Screenshot of error from Chrome]

I've tried using .length==0 but get the same error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks, Mark

Comment: Your error says that `document.getElementById("txtInput")` is `null`, not `populateNum`.

Comment: Hi - I've added the screenshot from Chrome to show the error.

Comment: @MarkTait That line doesn't try to access a `.value` property, so Chrome must be off. Try to log `document.getElementById("txtInput")` and see what it returns.

Comment: Most probably your script is loaded in `<head>` so it runs when the page is empty. Either move it before the closing `</body>` tag or use DOMContentLoaded event listener. Also you can debug the popup conveniently in devtools. The popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup, then click "inspect".